# gnome app launcher not detecting gksudo .desktop files

Tags: gnome, permissions, launcher, sudo, wireshark

I have an application : wireshark installed

the default /usr/share/applications/wireshark.desktop:

```
//...
Comment[uk]=Аналізатор мережевого трафіку
Icon=wireshark
TryExec=wireshark
Exec=wireshark %f
Terminal=false
//...
```

but wireshark requires to be run as root, thus:

```
gksudo wireshark
```

Implementing this into the .desktop file:

```
//...
Comment[uk]=Аналізатор мережевого трафіку
Icon=wireshark
TryExec=gksu wireshark
Exec=gksu wireshark %f
Terminal=false
//...
```

Afterwards, restarting Gnome session ( Alt+F2 -> r )

Searching for wireshark in the app launcher does not find it.

Should I place this .desktop file in another location?